# Как запустить файл .py в обход командной строки?

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.7

Решил сделать себе что-то "Мудрый совет на каждый день", только про иероглифы.

**Описание программы:**

Суть программы простая: есть скачанная таблица с сайта с полным списком кандзи (японские иероглифы(неважно)) в таком формате:
русский перевод, сам иероглиф, звучание 1, звучание 2, ключ иероглифа, номер ключа
и таким образом 2045 строчек. 
Я открываю файл 'ier.txt' питоном, читаю его питоном, записываю все строки этого файла как элементы list[]

```
f=open(r'ier.txt',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
textr=f.readlines()
for i in textr:
    i =i.strip("\n")
    i =i.replace("\t", " ")
```

Как видите, убираю пробелы и переносы. 
Беру рандомное число, потому что мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз какая-нибудь случайная строка открывалась.
Дальше задаю новый list[] путем запихивания в него строки из выдачи от textr.

```
rdd=random.randint(1,2044)
strr=textr[rdd]
stg=strr.split( )
```

Разделяю его пробелами и таким образом получаю что каждое слово это элемент.

```
arlen=len(stg)
n=1
self = Tk()
self.geometry('200x250')   
self.number_y = 5
self.number = 0
Label(self, text=stg[0].format(self.number),font=("Arial", 20)).place(x=0, y=self.number_y)
for i in range(arlen):
    self.number_y += 35
    self.number += 1
    Label(self, text=stg[n].format(self.number),font=("Arial", 20)).place(x=0, y=self.number_y)
    n+=1
self.mainloop()
```

Тут я создал форму и сделал цикл, который добавляет новый лейбл в форму в зависимости от количества элементов в list stg, потому что количество элементов там нефиксированное.

**В чем проблема?**

Проблема в том, что, если я открываю весь мой код в Python 3.7.3 IDLE, там жму кнопку Run(F5), программа запускается и работает красиво, от души. Но моя задача засунуть это дело в автозагрузку. И вот, нехитрыми манипуляциями я засунул ярлык от этой программы в автозагрузку, перезагружаю компьютер и... ничего не работает. Я решил сделать по-другому. Сделал ту же программу, только чтобы она запускалась через консоль. Дважды кликаю мышкой по файлу 'программа.py' - запустилось, нарисовалось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Уродливо правда, но работает. Дважды кликаю мышкой по файлу с программой, описанной выше - ничего. Хотя в IDLE все запускалось нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я решил открыть cmd и в командной строке одновременно стартануть питон и файл с программой .py. Командная строка мне ответила:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Попытка поиска решения в интернете результата не принесла. 
Я пытался настроить программу Python 3.7.3 IDLE и по совместительству Python 3.7.3 Shell как основные для открытия всех файлов типа .py, но при таком раскладе файл сразу открывается для ... редактирования, а не для запуска.

Comment: Если речь идёт о Windows - создайте bat файл с одной строкой аля C:\Python3.6\python.exe myscript.py.  Добавьте его в автозапуск, радуйтесь.

Comment: В свойствах ярлыка укажите текущую папку, где у вас лежит файл ier.txt. Скорее всего программа при запуске из автозагрузки просто не находит файл.

Comment: Послушайте, вы не могли бы меньше упражняться в эпистолярном жанре, а больше по существу писать? С трудом осилил ваш опус с лирическими отступлениями и идиомами.

Comment: Всё норм с эпистолярным жанром. Гораздо лучше, чем когда вопрос выглядит как "пейтон выбивает кокуюта ашипку чё делоть".

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev да ладно, тут половину можно смело сократить. Про убирание пробелов, переносов и прочие иероглифы.

Comment: С батником не получилось. Результат тот же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось в банальном:
У меня было установлено две разных версии `Python` на компьютере, и они вместе не стыковались, вызывая такую дурацкую ошибку. Я снес обе версии и все что связано с Питоном и установил заново Python 3.8. После этого мне выдало ошибку, что `n out of range`, легко поправил ее, и все заработало